# In android, how can I get the precise time a button was clicked (as opposed to when the onclick handler gets called)?

Tags: android

I want to get the exact time that a button is pressed.

Of course I can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` in the onClick handler, but presumably there is a fair bit of processing that happens between the button physically getting tapped and the onClick handler getting called. I don't know if this is of the order of nanoseconds or milliseconds (say if a garbage collection is running), but I'm wondering if there is any accessible value that is stored earlier in the processing that I could reference.

I suspect the answer is no, but I thought I'd ask anyway. Perhaps there is some undocumented, but accessible value?

Many thanks!

Comment: No i guess. Its only just matter of `ACTION_DOWN` and `ACTION_UP` for the touch event. You should probably check the Source code of `View.java`.

Comment: @ADM Thank you - you made me realise I should be listening to the touch event rather than the onclick event

Answer (score 0):

I think there are no ways to do it, all UI controls work in the Main-thread, the signals from low-level drivers (overlay-driver) don't handling immediately and put in a special queue for handling on the Main-thread. I guess, you're trying to catch an interval between the physical click and the button event in your code, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, yes I want to know the exact time button was actually physically clicked. It may be there's not much difference, but I'd be interested if anyone's looked into it.